How do I share my projects with external users to showcase my work in clickup and Jira?
I have been working on manual testing project and I have been using clickup as an project management tool and a bug tracking tool. Same thing goes for Jira. Now I want to showcase my work in GitHub but I don't know how people will view my work in clickup and jira. Can anyone help me figure this out?

What exactly do you want to show, that you cannot simply given then a link to Clickup and Jira?

I have reported bugs using jira and clickup and also added all the functionalities as stories there and want to showcase that to in my resume but I don't know how should I do it

If I got you right, you want to showcase that you are familiar with these tools and has experience using them.
From my experience you just need to add them in your resume, and no need to give a link or anything else, during the interviews you could be asked about the daily tasks and how do you use those tools.
